# I used the styled-components component, and I want to display a button next to it when the Input gets the focus, but it doesn’t work

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

[This is my code, can some one help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMUvw.png)

**I used the styled-components component, and I want to display a button next to it when the Input gets the focus, but it doesn’t work.**

Comment: Please try to use snippet editor instead of images while sharing your codes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think changing InputContainer's type to input is good option...

```
const InputContainer = styled.input`
  ...
  &:focus + ${CancelButton} {
    display: block;
  }
`
```